# Upgrading ReadBeanPHP version 3.x to 4.x in RedSlim library

Tags: composer-php, upgrade, redbean

Open the **composer.json** file in text editor. Find the below mentioned line in **composer.json** file and change the *3.x* to *4.x*

```
"gabordemooij/redbean": "4.*",
```

Save the **composer.json** file.

On the command line bash (terminal) and traverse to the directory  **redslim**

```
[milin@lap09 ~]$ cd public_html/redslim
```

Now run the command **composer update** in the terminal

```
[milin@lap09 ~]$ composer update
```

After the above command you will see some output from the composer command like this -

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Removing gabordemooij/redbean (v3.5.1)
  - Installing gabordemooij/redbean (v4.2.1)
    Loading from cache

Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. It's not clear what your question is Milin.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments. Actually I am not asking for question here but providing my solution that I have used to upgrade ReadBeanPHP and want to share with other developers.